# d3 transition is not a function

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am having a problem with my D3 code.

```
const hexagon = this.hexagonSVG.append('path')
  .attr('id', 'active')
  .attr('d', lineGenerator(<any>hexagonData))
  .attr('stroke', 'url(#gradient)')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3.5)
  .attr('fill', 'none')

const totalLength = (<any>hexagon).node().getTotalLength()

const _transition = this.d3.transition()
  .duration(DASH_ANIMATION)
  .ease(this.d3.easeLinear)

hexagon
  .attr('stroke-dasharray', totalLength + ' ' + totalLength)
  .attr('stroke-dashoffset', totalLength)
  .attr('stroke-dashoffset', 0)
  .transition(_transition)
```

This code was working perfectly fine for almost 6 months, but an error just came out of nowhere today.

"hexagon.attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).transition is not a function"

Can someone please tell me how I solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Did you upgrade from v3 to v4?Are you importing the separate modules or the default bundle?

Comment: Sorry, I am still quite new to d3 and Angular. I am currently using npm d3-ng2-service so I can't really sure about the version I am using.

Comment: Hi there. Looks like I am using v4 for d3

Answer (score 9):

For future reference: I ran into a similar issue and it seems to be a problem between webpack, yarn and d3-transition. The later extends the function of d3-selection, which somehow results in multiple d3-selection versions in the yarn.lock file (as described in [this issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/185)).

In my case explicitly adding d3-selection, removing the lock file and then running `yarn install` again fixed the issue.

It seems like every update of d3-transition recreates this problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting the Github link. The version that you posted didn't work for me, but I was able to find what worked for me on that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this when I was mix using `import * as d3 from 'd3';` and individual `import { select } from 'd3-selection'`. 
I overcome the issue by just using individual import, which I guess is the suggested way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity's sake on this old issue. I found another option for `d3@4.13.0`, which is to add this to your `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    "d3-selection": "1.3.0"
}
```

Then deleting your `yarn.lock` and then `yarn install` the project again to help yarn handle the version resolutions.

FYI: My `d3` dependencies in my `package.json` are (showing that I don't have `d3-selection` as a direct dependency):

```
    ...
    "d3": "4.13.0",
    "d3-geo-projection": "2.9.0",
    "d3-scale": "1.0.0",
    "d3-scale-chromatic": "3.0.0",
    ...
```

This seems to mainly be an issue with how yarn handle it's dependency resolution because, as a test, I was able to temporarily switch my project over to `npm` and had no issues.

This thread on Github lists a few alternative solutions to what I posted above (and worked for me): https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/185